# Left join multiple column using linq from 2 datatable and bind it to 1 datagridview

Tags: vb.net, linq, datagridview

Can you help me to understand linq, i'm googling it for almost whole day but still cannot get the architecture mindset properly.

Here's the issue,
I'am having 2 datatable from different database and i want to show in `datagridview` a left join `dataset` a and b in 3 columns (`OrderNum,OrderLine,OrderRelNum`)
in sql the query looks like this

```
Select *
From dataset1 a
left join dataset2 b
    on a.OrderNum = b.OrderNum 
    and a.OrderLine = b.OrderLine 
    and a.OrderRelNum = b.OrderRelNum
```

The question is how do i do this query in Linq and show them in datagridview?

This is my solve code to get the right query and datasource them into datagridview

```
Public Sub DataSetLinq120()
    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM po "
    strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM PO"
    Dim DA As New OdbcDataAdapter(strSQL, Connection)
    Dim DS As New DataSet

    DA.Fill(DS, "Source1")

    Dim DA2 As New OdbcDataAdapter(strSQL2, Connection2)
    Dim DS2 As New DataSet

    DA2.Fill(DS2, "Source2")

    Dim dt = DS.Tables("Source1")
    Dim dt2 = DS2.Tables("Source2")

    Dim custQuery = (From a In dt _
                    Group Join b In dt2 On a!OrderNum Equals b!OrderNum _
                    And a!OrderLine Equals b!OrderLine _
                    And a!OrderRelNum Equals b!OrderRelNum _
                    Into Data1 = Group _
                    From c In Data1.DefaultIfEmpty
                    Select New With {
                        .OrderNumber = a!OrderNum,
                        .OrderLine = a!OrderLine,
                        .OrderRelNumber = a!OrderRelNum,
                        .Stock_Status = If(c Is Nothing, "", c.Field(Of String)("Stock_Status")),
                        .Comments = If(c Is Nothing, "", c.Field(Of String)("Comments"))}).ToList

    DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
    DataGridView1.DataSource = custQuery

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good article from MSDN on how to perform left outer joins in LINQ: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx
You should be able to easily create a LEFT JOIN out of this.

Apart from that, I'm not sure why you don't want to simply handle the left join with SQL in this example. If you don't need the original datasets, I don't see why you wouldn't do this directly in SQL.

Comment: thx for your help, the reason i don't directly join in sql is the database are different between dataset 1 and dataset 2. the sql query above is just example what i'm want to do in linq

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Were you able to solve it with the example from MSDN ?

Comment: i'm still confusing with the architecture of the linq query for now i'm using the query i'm updated in the question